# Android - Need help accessing image from shared network

Tags: android, networking

I'm creating an app that loads images from a network. I have internet permission and access network state permission but I get cannot open file error. I'm using the absolute path when specifying the file ie \\192.168.1.100\d\.folder\image.jpg.

Is this possible or is there something else that i need to do first?

Comment: post your code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNC paths (of the form \\\ will NOT work by default on Android: Android does not natively support those sort of references (CIFS). You should either use HTTP and one of the toolkits that provides support for that (like [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)) or look at a library like [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/).

Comment: thanks. decided to use jcifs and it seems to work pretty well.